# Как подключить ble HM-10 с помощью Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

Кто может подключал bluetooth-модуль HM-10 на Qt и может поделиться написанным коротеньким драйвером?

Comment: https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/15256043382w025x52wj

Comment: А так задача редкая, вряд ли кто-нибудь такое уже делал. "Думайте сами, решайте сами."